# Given critical points, find the original function of two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, stationary-point

I am unsure how to attempt this question as it entails two variables.

Find a function  $f:ℝ^2→ℝ$ that has local extrema at $f(x,y)$ for all $[x,y]∈P$

$$P={\{[-8,5],[-7,6],[-5,2],[-3,-4],[5,5]}\}$$

N.B. The local extrema in your function must pass the 2-variable 2nd derivative test.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you mean $(x,y)$ instead of $[x,y]$?

Comment: The question given to me had $[x,y]$, however I see where you're coming from.